# Cross Validation in glmnet package

Tags: r, cross-validation, regularization, glmnet, elastic-net

I am using cross validation in glmnet package and have some difficulties in understanding foldid option. Why do I still get random results if I use foldid?

```
load("QuickStartExample.RData")
foldid=sample(1:10,size=length(y),replace=TRUE)
for(i in 1:10){
   print(cv.glmnet(x,y,foldid)$lambda.min)
}

# The outputs

[1] 0.1035043
[1] 0.09430923
[1] 0.09430923
[1] 0.09430923
[1] 0.02336112
[1] 0.1035043
[1] 0.08593106
[1] 0.03389298
[1] 0.01767183
[1] 0.09430923
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not pass `cv.glmnet` a `foldid` argument.

Let's look at the signature of `cv.glmnet`, taken from the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmnet/versions/2.0-10/topics/cv.glmnet)

```
cv.glmnet(x, y, weights, offset, lambda, type.measure, nfolds, foldid, grouped, keep,
      parallel, ...)
```

The third **positional** argument to `cv.glmnet` is `weights`, this is where you placed your `foldid` vector.  So `cv.glmnet` is interpreting the vector you named `foldid` as the `weights` argument, and using it as sample weights.

The correct call to do what you are after is

```
cv.glmnet(x, y, foldid = foldid)
```

You need to pass in your `foldid` as a **named** argument.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to use the named argument. Thanks for this :)